# Read bytea type row by row?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have a column with type of "bytea" in the table. In my case it's just .txt file. Is there any good way to read this file line by line and insert each row in another table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `encode(colname, 'escape')` turns the column into escaped text
2. `string_to_array` splits it into an array of `text[]`
3. `unnest()` turns the array into rows
4. `cross join lateral` is necessary to use the `with ordinality` to get the `rnum`

```
select id, rnum, tline 
  from your_table 
 cross join lateral unnest(
                      string_to_array(encode(stuff, 'escape'), E'\n')
                    ) with ordinality x(tline, rnum)
 order by id, rnum;
```

Comment: @xxx_coder_noscope Just remove the `rnum` from the select list.  I should have added an `order by id, rnum` to my query.  I will update my answer.  Even if you drop `rnum` from the columns list, it will still order correctly.